# image not being displayed in android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to download an image from MySQL database and display the image in an Android `ImageView`, but it is not being displayed. Below I have included code for my java file and php file. There are no errors, but in my logcat I get factory return null. I can't find where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Base64;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by GIOVANI on 10/19/2016.
 */

public class GetAllImages {

    public static String[] imageURLs;
    public static Bitmap[] bitmaps;

    public static final String JSON_ARRAY="result";
    public static final String IMAGE_URL = "url";
    private String json;
    private JSONArray urls;

    public GetAllImages(String json){
        this.json = json;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            urls = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getImage(JSONObject jo){
        URL url = null;
        Bitmap image = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(jo.getString(IMAGE_URL));
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return image;

    }

    public void getAllImages() throws JSONException {
        bitmaps = new Bitmap[urls.length()];

        imageURLs = new String[urls.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<urls.length();i++){
            imageURLs[i] = urls.getJSONObject(i).getString(IMAGE_URL);
            JSONObject jsonObject = urls.getJSONObject(i);
            bitmaps[i]=getImage(jsonObject);
        }
    }


}
```

And this is my php code:

```
    <?php

//Importing database 
require_once('dbConnect.php'); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM foto ";
//result 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

$result = array(); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){ 
array_push($result,array( "id"=>$row['id'],
"image"=>$row['image'],
"judul"=>$row['judul']
));
}

//Tampilkan dalam format json
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your logcat.

Comment: If you don't have a special reason, DO NOT store images inside your database.  You should store them in a web folder, possibly renamed with a GUID aka UUID and then in your database you have an image_name column with that filename and then simply point to it via HTML.

Storing images inside your database is the worst approach here unless you have a very specialized reason but I've never seen anybody in that situation, ever.

Answer (score 1):

for loading an image from the server.
you can use any image loading API. like
Glide or Picasso or Universal Image Loader.

Glide is recommended by Google.
[source](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)

you can easily integrate and avoid some memory and slow loading issue as well.

as like :

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load("http://nuuneoi.com/uploads/source/playstore/cover.jpg")
    .fit()
    .centerCrop()
    .into(ivImgPicasso);
```

so enjoy it.

Happy Coading.